# React Native: Autocomplete item not clickable after defining `renderItem`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I am new to React and wanted to create a search bar where:

1. A user could type some text
2. Autocomplete suggestions appear based on the input
3. When a suggestion is clicked, the clicked option will log to the console (eventually this will be replaced with something more useful)

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

export default function App() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (text) => {
    setInputText(text);
    // TODO: implement an API call that will fetch suggestions
    const predefinedSuggestions = [
      'Coupe & Flute', 'Coup Style Chicken', 'Coup d\'état', 'Coup the loop',
      'Canlis', 'Canon', 'Checkmat Jiu Jitsu' 
    ];
    const filteredSuggestions = predefinedSuggestions.filter((item) =>
      item.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase())
    );
    setSuggestions(filteredSuggestions);
  };

  const handleSelectSuggestion = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
    setInputText(text);
    setSuggestions([]);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Add Item</Text>
      <Autocomplete
        value={inputText}
        onChangeText={handleInputChange}
        placeholder="Enter some text..."
        data={suggestions}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSelectSuggestion(item)}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The key part is:

```
      <Autocomplete
        value={inputText}
        onChangeText={handleInputChange}
        placeholder="Enter some text..."
        data={suggestions}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSelectSuggestion(item)}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

Especially

```
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSelectSuggestion(item)}>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
```

#### What was I expecting

My expectation was that this would display a item from the list of remaining suggestions and if that item were clicked, it would trigger the `handleSelectSuggestion` function.  This is not happening but according to ChatGPT and other websites this should work.

#### What is happening

The dropdown appears and as I type the list of suggestions gets smaller but you cannot click the items in the list and nothing logs to the console when items are clicked.  Seems pretty similar to: https://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input/issues/115 which didn't look like it was ever resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem arises from the fact that `renderItem` doesn't seem to be a valid prop of the `Autocomplete` component. Based on the [Snack example](https://byteburgers.com/autocomplete) provided in the repo you linked, I got your example to work by replacing `renderItem` with `flatListProps`:

```
<Autocomplete
    value={inputText}
    onChangeText={handleInputChange}
    placeholder='Enter some text...'
    data={suggestions}
    flatListProps={{
        keyExtractor: (_, idx) => idx.toString(),
        renderItem: ({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleSelectSuggestion(item)}>
                <Text>{item}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you!  It looks like this works but is there a specific reason you included: `keyExtractor: (_, idx) => idx.toString(),` not 100% sure what it does but it doesn't look like we use that string do we?

Comment: The Autocomplete component uses a FlatList internally, which uses keys for caching and tracking item re-ordering. You can learn more about it [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#keyextractor).